# Is it any way to auto refresh Redshift Matearilized view based on external table?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, materialized-views, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have materialized view in Redshift, that based on data from external Redshift Spectrum table, so it's impossible to use Redshift auto refresh feature.

I just don't wont to refresh it by hand.

I don't care much about data consistency, so delay for some time (up to 1+ hour) is fine for me.

So, **is it any way to update materialized view automatically?** Maybe, it's possible to configure some TTL for it? Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you want the view to be updated whenever there is a change in your data or from x to x time?

Comment: I'm fine with both options.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the location of the Spectrum files is Amazon S3.
You can automate the update by scheduled Lambda that triggers periodically.
You can also establish a trigger that fires every time a file is created in a part of a bucket. This trigger creates an event that initiates a Lambda function that issues the desired update.

I'd start simple if you can and work up to Redshift Data API and Step functions.

This first option might be a better solution than invoking a Lambda on every object upload, especially if you are receiving lots of files continuously.